# How to neatly deconstruct newtypes nested into records?

Tags: pattern-matching, purescript, newtype

I use a *newtype* as field of a record, and pattern matching on the "parent" type to extract the nested value is cumbersome:

```
newtype CityName = CityName String
newtype City = City {
  name :: CityName
}
instance showCity :: Show City where
  show (City { name }) = case name of (CityName cn) -> "City(" <> cn <> ")"
```

I can deconstruct the "parent" type, but then I use another pattern matching to extract the wrapped String - even if the *newtype* only has one data constructor. It would be more convenient to deconstruct the whole type in just one pattern.

Is this possible? If so, I cannot get the syntax right. I tried something like `show (City { name :: (CityName cn) }) = cn` but it gives me syntax errors. [PureScript by Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read) did not help me either, but maybe there is neater way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried is almost right, but you only need a single colon when pattern matching records:

```
instance showCity :: Show City where
  show (City { name: CityName cn }) = "City(" <> cn <> ")"
```

Double colon is only used for annotating types, value level stuff always uses a single colon.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Is this syntax documented somewhere, or is it just the same as in Haskell? I wonder if there are more deconstruction "tricks" that I do not know about.

Comment: There's a language guide on the Github Wiki here: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Language-Guide#record-patterns. It's probably also covered in the PureScript book, but that's not really a reference so perhaps not the easiest place to look for this kind of thing!